# Is there a way to condition inside an array using update batch? CodeIgniter PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to update grades of student using update batch (multiple update)

However the problem arises when conditioning in the model, whereas the array condition does not accept else if statement

> in this line, 'equiv' => $data['grade'][$i] == 65 ? 5 : 0, is there a way to make it a full condition statement where I can use else if and remove the else or `:0` at the end of the line. The `:0` makes all other data 0 which those data should not be affected.

```
public function updateAll(){
    $id = $this->input->post('studentID');

    $data = $this->input->post();
    
        for($i = 0; $i < (count($data['studentID'])); $i++){
        
            $batch[] = array(
            'studentID' => $data['studentID'][$i],
            'grade' => $data['grade'][$i],
            'equiv' => $data['grade'][$i] == 65 ? 5 : 0
            );

        }

    return $this->db->update_batch('tbl_college_grades', $batch, 'studentID');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

THIS IS WORK FOR ME, GOOD LUCK

```
public function updateAll(){
    $id = $this->input->post('studentID');

    $data = $this->input->post();
    $selected_equiv;
    
        for($i = 0; $i < (count($data['studentID'])); $i++){
            data['grade'][$i] == 65 ? $selected_equiv = 5 : 0
            $batch[] = array(
            'studentID' => $data['studentID'][$i],
            'grade' => $data['grade'][$i],
            'equiv' => $selected_equiv
            );

        }

    return $this->db->update_batch('tbl_college_grades', $batch, 'studentID');
}
```

Comment: Since when are we allowed to refer to a variable without the $ in PHP?